# Qt novice: base class for QLineEdit and QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qwidget

Is there another class besides `QWidget` which holds all generic functions for both? Something like QEdit...

As an example I'd like to reference cut(), copy() and paste(), but it looks like I have to dynamic cast the `QWidget`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Your question is unclear, explain yourself better.

Comment: What's your problem with dynamic cast? (which in Qt you should use `qobject_cast`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way besides `QWidget`. The reason is that `QLineEdit` is inherited directly from `QWidget`. You can see the full hierarchy of Qt classes [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/hierarchy.html)

Comment: thank you. But it makes me wonder why did they do it like this? Those cut(), copy(), paste() and canPaste() functions and probably more can be set in a base class from which those 2 can be inherited.

Comment: @Igor Here we can only guess. These functions didn't seem so important for Qt architects. They were thinking more about QFrame base class

Comment: `QWidget` is-a `QObject` and that makes it a bit more powerful than the raw C++ types due to introspection :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to dynamic-cast anything: this is typically a sign of bad design. Qt generally has very few interface classes - they usually have the word `Abstract` somewhere in the name, and are not really pure interfaces as they have non-abstract base classes, like e.g. `QObject`. Thus there was no pattern to follow, and no need for abstracting out the edit operations into an interface.

There are several approaches to overcome this:

1. Leverage the fact that the methods in question are known by the metaobject system. Note that `invokeMethod` takes a method **name**, not signature.

   ```
   bool cut(QWidget * w) {
      return QMetaObject::invokeMethod(w, "cut");
   }
   bool copy(QWidget * w) {
      return QMetaObject::invokeMethod(w, "copy");
   }
   //...
   ```

   You can use the free-standing functions such as above on any widget that supports the editing operations.
2. As above, but cache the method lookup not to pay its costs repeatedly. Note that `indexOfMethod` takes a method **signature**, not merely its name.

   ```
   static QMetaMethod lookup(QMetaObject * o, const char * signature) {
      return o->method(o->indexOfMethod(signature));
   }
   struct Methods {
      QMetaMethod cut, copy;
      Methods() {}
      explicit Methods(QMetaObject * o) :
         cut(lookup(o, "cut()")),
         copy(lookup(o, "copy()")) {}
      Methods(const Methods &) = default;
   };
   // Meta class names have unique addresses - they are effectively memoized.
   // Dynamic metaobjects are an exception we can safely ignore here.
   static QMap<const char *, Methods> map;
   static const Methods & lookup(QWidget * w) {
      auto o = w->metaObject();
      auto it = map.find(o->className());
      if (it == map.end())
        it = map.insert(o->className(), Methods(o));
      return *it;
   }
   bool cut(QWidget * w) {
      lookup(w).cut.invoke(w);
   }
   bool copy(QWidget * w) {
      lookup(w).copy.invoke(w);
   }
   //...
   ```
3. Define an interface and provide implementations specialized for widget types. This approach's only benefit is that it's a bit faster than `QMetaMethod::invoke`. It makes little sense to use this code for clipboard methods, but it could be useful to minimize overhead for small methods that are called very often. I'd advise not to over-engineer it unless a benchmark shows that it really helps. The previous approach (#2 above) should be quite sufficient.

   ```
   // Interface

   class IClipboard {
   public:
      virtual cut(QWidget *) = 0;
      virtual copy(QWidget *) = 0;
      virtual paste(QWidget *) = 0;
   };

   class Registry {
      // all meta class names have unique addresses - they are effectively memoized
      static QMap<const char *, IClipboard*> registry;
   public:
      static void register(const QMetaObject * o, IClipboard * clipboard) {
         auto name = o->className();
         auto it = registry.find(name);
         if (it == registry.end())
            registry.insert(name, clipboard);
         else
            Q_ASSERT(it->value() == clipboard);
      }
      static IClipboard * for(QWidget * w) {
         auto it = registry.find(w->metaObject()->className());
         Q_ASSERT(registry.end() != it);
         return it->value();
      }
      static void unregister(const QMetaObject * o) {
         registry.remove(o->className());
      }
   };

   template <class W> class ClipboardWidget : public IClipboard {
      Q_DISABLE_COPY(ClipboardWidget)
   public:
      cut(QWidget * w) override { static_cast<W*>(w)->cut(); }
      copy(QWidget * w) override { static_cast<W*>(w)->copy(); }
      paste(QWidget * w) override { static_cast<W*>(w)->paste(); }
      ClipboardWidget() {
        Registry::register(&W::staticMetaObject(), this);
      }
      ~ClipboardWidget() {
        Registry::unregister(&W::staticMetaObject());
      }
   };

   // Implementation

   QMap<const char *, IClipboard*> Registry::registry;
   static ClipboardWidget<QTextEdit> w1;
   static ClipboardWidget<QLineEdit> w2;

   void yourCode() {
      //...
      Registry::for(widget)->cut(widget);
   }
   ```